# vertical accordion jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML (should not be changed)

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;">
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link1">main link 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link2">main link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li {position:relative;}
div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul {display:none;}

ul.wpsc_top_level_categories {padding-bottom:0 !important;}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li {}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li:hover {}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li ul li a span {background:none !important;}
span.collapse-arrow {cursor:pointer;background:red;width:10px;height:9px;float:right;margin-top:5px;}
```

jQuery

```
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul').slideUp().hide();
$('.wpsc_categories').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the Default Action
    if (e.target.className == 'collapse-arrow') { // Trigger only
                                                  // If clicked on span
        $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').slideToggle();
    }

});
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li a').append('<span class="collapse-arrow">&nbsp;</span>');
```

here is My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nwbY7/23/

1. only the red square can activate the dropdown slide
2. links should redirect to a url (its not going anywhere)
3. html structure should never be changed

I really badly in need of anyhelp... :-(

Comment: What's the problem? It works perfectly.

Comment: the links does not go anywhere

Comment: I think all the links are disabled

Comment: Of course they don't, as you don't tell them too. You tell it to go to the mysterious place `link1`. I think the browser interprets this as the current place, `/link1`, which on JSFiddle, is a null link. Have you tested this code on Apache or some other real web server?

Comment: even adding links to it, it still does not work

see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nwbY7/24/

Comment: As I said, try it on a real webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event handler is preventing the browser from doing what is normally does with < a >  tags: go to a new URL.

`e.preventDefault()` is being fired for all link clicks. You only want to do that if you are handling the collapse-arrow click. This seemed to work for me on jsfiddle:

```
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul').slideUp().hide();
$('.wpsc_categories').on('click', 'a', function(e) {

if (e.target.className == 'collapse-arrow') { // Trigger only
                                              // If clicked on span
    $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the Default Action
}

});
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li a').append('<span class="collapse-arrow">&nbsp;</span>');​
```

Note all I did was move `e.preventDefault()` to inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got it to work.... only problem is that I want the plus sign to change minus sign when collapsed.

working sample here http://jsfiddle.net/nwbY7/25/

HTML

```
 <div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;">
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link1">main link 1</a>
            <ul class="wpsc_second_level_categories">
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link2">main link 2</a>
            <ul class="wpsc_second_level_categories">
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span.CatExpander {float:right;cursor:pointer;}
.wpsc_second_level_categories {display:none;}
```

Javascript

```
//<![CDATA[
(function($)
{
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".wpsc_top_level_categories > li:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"CatExpander\">[+]</span>");

$(".CatExpander").click(function()
{
$(this).toggleClass("CatExpanded").siblings("ul").slideToggle(500);
return false;
}).eq(0).addClass("CatExpanded").end().slice(1).siblings("ul").hide();
});
})(jQuery);
//]]>
```

Comment: this is for use of the product category widget in wp e-commerce